# Workaround for missing descending index feature in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

We have a problem with our production environment which uses a modified version of jBPM that has support for priorities. Indices present are:

```
| JBPM_TIMER |          1 | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ |            1 | PRIORITY_        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| JBPM_TIMER |          1 | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ |            2 | DUEDATE_         | A         |          51 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
```

The problematic query:

```
mysql> explain select * from JBPM_TIMER where PRIORITY_ < 0 order by PRIORITY_ ASC, DUEDATE_ desc;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | JBPM_TIMER | range | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ | 5       | NULL |   10 | Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query with PRIORITY_ sorted ascending instead:

```
mysql> explain select * from JBPM_TIMER where PRIORITY_ < 0 order by PRIORITY_ ASC, DUEDATE_ asc;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | JBPM_TIMER | range | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ | JBPM_TIMER_DUEDATE__PRIORITY_ | 5       | NULL |   10 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Googling around suggests that the solution to this is to add another column (REVERSEPRIORITY_) that contains the value of PRIORITY_ * -1 and index that one instead. This seems to me like a pretty ugly solution so I want to ask you folks if you have better ones!

Comment: Followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256568/why-does-mysql-use-the-wrong-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-PRIORITY` is the best solution.

However, you can use `MySQL` `FORCE INDEX` and `STRAIGHT_JOIN` to emulate `SKIP SCAN`:

```
SELECT  jt *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT priority
        FROM    JBPM_TIMER
        ORDER BY
                priority DESC
        ) jtd
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        JBPM_TIMER jt FORCE INDEX (ix_JBPM_TIMER_priority_duedate)
ON      jt.priority >= jtd.priority
        AND jt.priority <= jtd.priority
```

You need to create an index on `(priority, duedate)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_JBPM_TIMER_priority_duedate ON JBPM_TIMER (priority, duedate)
```

Note that unlike your original solution, **this really is an ugly hack** whose behavior can change in the future releases of `MySQL`.

I'm posting it here only as a workaround if you cannot change your schema.

Don't use it if there is a slightest chance of your `MySQL` being upgraded.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer. We have rewritten the patch and we now use -PRIORITY instead.